# How do I rewrite these ERB statements for HAML in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, haml, yield, document-body

In my layout I want:

```
<body class="<%= yield (:body_class) %>">
```

And I also want to call it from another template:

```
<% content_for :body_class, "my_class" %>
```

Answer (score 3):

In layout:

```
%body(:class => yield(:body_class))
```

and in template:

```
- content_for :body_class, 'my_class'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use online converter for future reference

Follow this link

http://html2haml.heroku.com/

Answer (score 0):

Voted too quickly. I'm not sure why, but these answers didn't work for me.
A friend gave me this answer, which works:

```
%body{ class: "#{yield(:body_class)}"}
```

but for the template, is what Marek suggested,

```
- content_for :body_class, 'my_class'
```